# What's the difference between a companion object and a singleton class in Scala (Guice)

Tags: scala

I was wondering what was the difference between a companion object and a class declared with @Singleton ?

As I understand, you can only have one instance of both. You can use dependency injection with the class and not with the object but apart from that I don't see much difference to be honest.

Comment: What's this annotation `@Singleton`? I've never seen it.

Comment: I guess its from `Guice` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar stuff. Objects is how Scala allows you to create singleton objects.

Things to keep in mind:

- Singleton classes (Java Style) are easier to test than Objects. This is because you can create different classes in your tests but you can never create more than one Objects
- Objects cannot have a constructor
- Objects cannot be inherited

Answer (score 1):

Well to put it simply.
A singleton object named the same as a class is called a companion object.
Also a companion object must be defined inside the same source file as the class.
Also are you using `Guice` ?  That @Singleton is a Guice thing i guess.

Answer (score 1):

As the name reflects, Singleton in Scala has one instance throughout the application life-cycle. Example of a singleton is Nil which denotes an empty List.

Companion objects on the other hand are helper objects for case classes created in Scala where you can put custom object constructors(apply), implicit conversions, decomposers (unapply). When you define a case class automatically a companion object gets defined.

Answer (score 1):

One other difference is that serializing references to Scala singleton objects uses custom code that will always resolve the single instance of that object that exists within the respective classloader.